# How to render Markdown Text from database in a Razor view?

Tags: markdown, servicestack

So I am handling my own custom Route mapping (rather than allowing ServiceStack to automatically handle it), simply because all of my data is stored inside of a database, page content and all. I have a series of _Layout.cshtml files, and my Markdown is stored as a string.

So I suppose I am asking, what type of Service do I need to inherit  (regular Service?) for my mapped Route, and what do I need to return to state "use Layout X and Markdown in string Y" ?

I have read through the examples on the ServiceStack Wiki and new example page, and was unable to find any samples for achieving this (everything seemed to be reading Markdown from a file, and Razor reading variables from a Database).

Please let me know if I am not clear in my question, and I will be happy to modify it accordingly.

--

### EDIT

Some clarification:

Yes I got the regular Razor pages to load.
Yes I got the regular Markdown from files to load.

I am simply now curious how to render Markdown into the Razor method "RenderBody()" which is in a string (from my database).

Comment: Please try first to create that without your custom routing (btw, why doesn't ServiceStack built-in doesn't fit?). What did you already try and where started the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to render a **Markdown text as HTML** (not Markdown Razor, ie no razor functionality!) you need to do these two steps:

```
var renderer = new MarkdownSharp.Markdown();
string html = renderer.Transform("___your_markdown_markup_here___");
```

Now you only have to add the rendered HTML to your Razor view at the appropriate place for example.

---

However, if your goal is to render a normal **Markdown view (ie `.md` file in your ServiceStack project) in a Razor view**, you need to follow this quote:

> #### Include Partial Markdown views in Razor pages
>
> We loved Markdown and Razor so much that included in ServiceStack is
>   an enhanced version of Markdown with Razor functionality and Syntax
>   called Markdown Razor which should be instantly familiar to existing
>   Razor users.
>
> As we expect Razor + Markdown to be an increasingly popular
>   combination we've extend @Html.Partial() support to also embed
>   Partials from different View Engines. This feature lets you embed any
>   Markdown Page as we've done in each of the content-heavy Rockstar
>   pages using the standard Razor Partial syntax:
>
> ```
> @Html.Partial("Content")
> ```
>
> Which tells ServiceStack to embed a Partial named Content inside the page at that location. First it will look for a Partial named
>   Content.cshtml followed by a Partial named Content.md if it reaches
>   the Markdown Razor View Engine. Initially it searches the current
>   directory, followed by any matching Partials in the /Views/Shared
>   folder.

*Quoted from http://razor.servicestack.net.*