# Where can I find the code that converts PR descriptions into HTML

Tags: azure-devops

Pull requests' (PRs) descriptions use Markdown that's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance?view=vsts), and when the PR is viewed in a browser, that Markdown content is converted into HTML and looks "pretty".

Where can I find the code that converts it from Markdown to HTML, so I can leverage the same algorithms in my (internal-only) code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we can not see the source code. It should be something like the Markdown editor/viewer.

So if you mean you want to render the Markdown with the "`pretty`" formatting offline, then you can use the existing Markdown editor/Tools such as [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) or [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) or any others.

> Showdown is a JavaScript Markdown to HTML converter, based on the
>   original works by John Gruber. Showdown can be used client side (in
>   the browser) or server side (with Node.js).

If you are interested in the codes, then you can reference the open source code of [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) or [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) on GitHub.

Other related questions:

*[How to render Markdown Text from database in a Razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919153/how-to-render-markdown-text-from-database-in-a-razor-view)*